# Error Message from W3 Total Cache when .htaccess Rules Cannot Be Modified?

Tags: plugins, multisite, htaccess, plugin-w3-total-cache

I have just installed the Plugin " [W3 Total Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/) " .I have enabled permalinks too. Then it is showing a message

> Browser Cache feature is not
>   operational. Your .htaccess rules
>   could not be modified. Please verify
>   /home/..../public_html/..../.htaccess
>   has the following rules:

SO I have pasted the code it has shown on with that message to my .htaccess file .But still it is showing the same error .Am I missing something?

It is the code shown and I have added to .htaccess file

```
 # BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
        BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
        BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css application/x-javascript text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "\.(css|js)$">
    FileETag None
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
         Header set X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.1.1"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|rtf|rtx|svg|svgz|txt|xsd|xsl|xml)$">
    FileETag None
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
         Header set X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.1.1"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|swf|tar|tif|tiff|wav|wma|wri|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip)$">
    FileETag None
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
         Header set X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.1.1"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END W3TC Browser Cache
```

(I have added the same code here.Please let me know If adding such a long code is inappropriate here .I will remove it from this question)

Comment: @user391 This question is more of a specific support type question than a community wiki.  You might get a better result by going through the normal support channel for W3 Total Cache which is to use the w3-total-cache tag on The WordPress.org forums: http://wordpress.org/tags/w3-total-cache Fredrick, the plugin author, answers all questions there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience with W3 Total Cache this error is triggered when the plugin cannot write to the .htaccess file.  It also suggests chmod 777 to the file and has a button that says "try-again" that you can click after changing the permissions to .htaccess.

I would suggest chmod 777 to .htaccess, click try again, then change the permissions back afterwards.  If this is not possible then you will need to paste the code into the file above the WordPress rewrite rules making sure not to replace them.

The plugin has a set of rules for each caching method that need to be added to various .htaccess files.  To find the rules needed for each file go to performance - install:

The code you posted above is missing the mime type rules that should be in the browser cache .htaccess.

[image] [image]
[image]